# Combining __table_args__ with constraints from mixin classes in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, declarative

In SQLAlchemy, I have read on how to combine the `__table_args__` from different mixins when declaring a declarative.

[Combining Table/Mapper Arguments from Multiple Mixins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html?highlight=combining%20table%20args%20from%20multiple%20mixins#combining-table-mapper-arguments-from-multiple-mixins)

The question I had is, the example shows how this is done at the end of the chain (final class in the MRO), but how would one achieve this say, if I had these Mixins and wanted it to occur in the `MyClientMixin` or `Base` class to avoid duplicating this code for other types of mixins?

```
class LaneCarrierCommitmentSummaryMixin(object):
    """ Lane Carrier Commitment Summary.

    A base class for LCCS to mixin with a client specific class.
    """

    __tablename__ = 'lane_carrier_commitment_summary'
    __table_args__ = ((UniqueConstraint(['hashmap_key', 'bow'],
                                        name='uq_lane_carrier_commitment_summary_hashmap_key_bow')),)

class MyClientMixin(object):
    """ MyClient Mixin class for providing the ETL schema. """

    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'myclient_etl'}

class MyClientLaneCarrierCommitmentSummary(LaneCarrierCommitmentSummaryMixin, DateTrackedMixin, MyClientMixin, Base):
    pass
```

I am struggling a bit with this concept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This base class will search all mixins for `__table_args__` to add, then check the current class for `__local_table_args__` to add.  This way, `__local_table_args__` doesn't clash with the declared attr.  The base classes (`cls.mro()`) are checked in reverse order so that mixins lower down the chain are overridden by higher mixins.

```
def _process_args(cls, attr, out_args, out_kwargs):
    try:
        args = getattr(cls, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        return

    if isinstance(args, Mapping):  # it's a dictionary
        out_kwargs.update(args)
    else:  # it's a list
        if isinstance(args[-1], Mapping):  # it has a dictionary at the end
            out_kwargs.update(args.pop())

        out_args.extend(args)

class Base():
    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        args = []
        kwargs = {}

        for mixin in reversed(cls.mro()):
            _process_args(mixin, '__mapper_args__', args, kwargs)

        _process_args(mixin, '__local_mapper_args__', args, kwargs)

        return kwargs  # mapper only takes dict

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        args = []
        kwargs = {}

        for mixin in reversed(cls.mro()):
            _process_args(mixin, '__table_args__', args, kwargs)

        _process_args(cls, '__local_table_args__', args, kwargs)

        args.append(kwargs)  # [item, item, ...,  kwargs]
        return tuple(args)
```

All your mixins should define `__table_args__` as normal, but the "real" class inheriting from `Base` should define `__local_table_args__`.